# How can I prove that $Z_i(k)$ is an exponential martingale?

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

I consider $$Z_n(c):= \exp\{c S^*_n- f(-c)n\}$$ with $f(k):=\log E(e^{kS_1})$ , $S_i=z+i-\sum\limits_{j=1}^iY_j$, $(Y_j)_j$ are i.i.d, $Y_j \in \mathbb{N}_0$ and $S^*_i:=-S_i$

$z$ should be a fixed value equal or greater than zero.

Edit:
I got: $$E[Z_{t+1}| \mathcal{F_t}]= E[Z_t e^{cY_{t+1}-f(-c)}|\mathcal{F_t} ]=
Z_t E[e^{cY_{t+1}-f(-c)}|\mathcal{F_t}]= Z_t E[e^{cY_{t+1}-f(-c)}] \overset{?}{=} Z_t$$

How can I verify the last step?

What do I choose for my filtration: $$\mathcal{F_t}=\sigma(S^*_1,....,S^*_t)$$ or

$$\mathcal{F_t}=\sigma(Z_1,....,Z_t)$$

Comment: Try to follow these two steps; (1) Factor $Z_n(k)$ in the form $Z_n(k) = Z_{n-1}(k) W_n(k)$ where the term $W_n(k)$ only depends on $Y_n$, and (2) Use the fact that $Y_n$ is independent of $\{Y_j : 1 \leq j \leq n-1\}$ to show that the conditional expectation of $Z_n(k)$ given $\{Z_1(k), \ldots, Z_{n-1}(k)\}$ is equal to $Z_{n-1}(k)$.

Comment: I get $Z_n(k)=Z_{n-1} \cdot e^{cY_n}$

Comment: @panini How can I go on from that formally. Do I write: $E[Z_n(k)| Z_1=i_1,...Z_{n-1}=i_{n-1}]]$

Comment: @panini: How can I express the conditional expectation in terms of the filtration in this context. How does the filtration look like?

Comment: Is your factorization correct. Shouldn't it be $Z_n(k) = Z_{n-1} e^{cY_n - f(-k)}$? Regarding the second step: you can define the filtration to be $\mathcal{F}_t = \sigma (Z_1, \ldots, Z_t)$ for $t \geq 1$.

Comment: I see. Your idea is $((n-1)+1) \cdot f(-k)$ .So I have to prove: $E[Z_s |Z_t]= Z_t$ for $s>t$

Comment: @panini Since $Y_i \in \mathbb{N_0}, Z_i$ can only be in $\mathbb{Z}$. So I am able to specify $E[Z_s| Z_{t}=i_t,....Z_1(t)=i_1]$?

Comment: Maybe I stick to the general defiintion:$ E[Z_s|F_t]= E[Z_t e^{c\sum_{i=t+1}^sY_i -(s-t)f(-k)} |F_t] $

Comment: @panini: How can I go on from here?

Comment: $e^{c\sum_{i=t+1}^sY_i -(s-t)f(-k)} E[Z_t  |F_t]  = e^{c\sum_{i=t+1}^sY_i -(s-t)f(-k}) Z_t$

Comment: For martingales, you only need to prove this for $s=t+1$. The general result for any $s>t$ will follow from this.  Using the fact that $Z_t$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$ measurable, it can be treated as a constant in the conditional expectation, i.e., $\mathbb{E}[Z_{t+1}|\mathcal{F}_t] = Z_t \mathbb[e^{cY_{t+1} - f(-k)}|\mathcal{F}_t] = \mathbb{E}[e^{cY_{t+1} - f(-k)}]$ where the last equality uses that that $Y_{t+1}$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_t$.

Comment: I see you only forgot $Z_t$ in the last equality

Comment: You only have to argue why $E[e^{cY_ {t+1} - f(-k)  ]  }=1$. Why is that?

Comment: Yes, you are right! I missed the $Z_{t}$ in the last equality. The reason is that it suffices to show that $\mathbb{E}[Z_{t+1}|\mathcal{F}_t] = Z_t$ to show that $(Z_t)_{t \geq 1}$ is a martingale adapted to the filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 1}$. See the definition here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(probability_theory)

Comment: @panini: But in the end I get $Z_t \cdot \mathbb{E}(e^{cY_{t+1}-f(-k)}$ Therefore I have an extra factor. What do I miss?

Comment: @panini: Can you tell me what I can do with the factor?

Comment: You have done most of the work. It remains to compute the expectation. For that you need to find the relation between $\mathbb{E}[e^{cY_{t+1}}]$ and $f(-k)$. Also, I think to show that it is a martingale, some additional conditions may be required on the constant $c$ and perhaps $z$ as well.

Comment: @panini: I made mistake:( I should  be $f(-c)$. Therefore I get: $\mathbb{E}(\frac{e^{cY_{t+1}}}{\mathbb{E}(-cS_1)}$

Comment: @panini Does this help? Can I get 1 here?